# Mariadb unix_socket (without password) or mysql_native_password what is safer?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, unix-socket

I have informed myself and apparently there should be a connection from zb. to create a PHP script via the unix_soket (no password is needed and the connection only works via localhost) since no TCP connection is established and therefore no eavesdropping is possible.

Is it correct that it is safe to use the Unix_socket or is it only good for root connections (and is it always without a password or can I add a password to unix_socket?)

Comment: Your database should always have a password. Leaving this open is asking for trouble.

Comment: But unix only alow localhost connections so there is no way to come in from outside the network and with Unix_socked you don't need SSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a description of the tradeoffs on [the unix_socket MariaDB knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#security).

All connections via the unix socket, whether using unix_socket authentication or not, are resistant against eaves dropping.

A PHP script with a password is less security as when the password is disclosed it can be used by other users. A person with the same access as the php script runs would need to find the password in the script. Maybe this offers some security.

unix_socket is just as effective on any unix user, root or otherwise.

From [MariaDB-10.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/) multiple authentication mechanisms are possible for a single user. These are in an `OR` context so adding a password weakens the security of the account.

Comment: Since I only allow localhost connections to my database, I can also use a password. It's probably even increases the security because if someone managed to operate Codeinjetion he would not only need the name of the database and the user but also the password (if I don't know the name of the connection function). For me it was primarily about the security that even if I use a password, ie `mysql_native_password`, I do not need an SSL certificate or protocol to establish a tap-protected connection.

Comment: Or do I get it wrong and the password really encrypts the sent content and not just the access via the user to the database?

Comment: regardless of if its password, unix_socket or tls, a code injection probably has a global `$db` connection variable or at least the configuration available so all mechanism are equally as vulnerable in that respect. On a unix socket (localhost) connection, interception requires a root user privileges, and if you've lost that you've lost all the CIA. Passwords, like unix_socket, is purely an authentication mechanism, if you use something like wireshark you'll be able to see all the traffic. The `mysql_native_password` mechanism has resilience against replay attacks as I recall.

Comment: But if I choose the unix_socket ther is no password witch I have to use to connect to the DB from my website right? But is it possible to do it with other user then root? (So Unix_socket is safe against  wireshark and my mysql_native_password not?)

Comment: In other words, does mysql_native_password also use the unix_soket? So is it safe?

Comment: There's unix socket connections, the connection to localhost aka /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock, and unix_socket authentication. The socket connection can use any authentication and is safe.

Comment: So mysql_native_password is just ja authentication Kind which use the unix soked automatic with localhost connections right?